# "fatal: Authentication failed for..." error when try to git push --set-upstream origin <newbranch>

Tags: git, authentication, push, branch

So I started working on a repository MM, where I use a remote machine to run it(not sure if it's relevant). I am connected to the machine, and I cloned the repository, and then added SSH key to my git as described in the GitHub page. Then I wanted to push my changes to a new branch- X, however when I try to push (just "git push") or "git push --set-upstream origin X" it asks me for "Username for 'https://github.com':" and Password, when I enter my GitHub username and password it says: "remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/MM/directory.git/'" I tried to push a change directly from the git website to see if there's an issue with my permissions for this repo but it worked (so I do have the permission to write) I am not sure what to do... Any help would be much appreciated :) thanks!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22remote%3A+Support+for+password+authentication+was+removed+on+August+13%2C+2021.%22